# EF Core 'InMemoryProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I cannot find why this IQueryable isn't working, I've tried some different apporaches but always I fallback to the same error, *'InMemoryProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core*:

```
var q = _QueryService.GetSomeInformation(db, cp.Attributes, min, max);

        var query = q
            .Join(db.SomeTable
                    .Where(mc => mc.Attribute.Total >= minimumValue),
                s => s.Code,
                c => c.Code,
                (s, c) => new {s, c})
            //.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(@t => new {@t.c.Year, @t.c.Month}, @t => @t.c)
            .Select(cg => new
            {

                cg.Key.Year,
                cg.Key.Month,
                P1 = cg.Average(i => i.Attribute.P1),
                P2 = cg.Average(i => i.Attribute.P2),
                P3 = cg.Average(i => i.Attribute.P3),
                P4 = cg.Average(i => i.Attribute.P4),
                P5 = cg.Average(i => i.Attribute.P5),
                P6 = cg.Average(i => i.Attribute.P6),
                Total = cg.Average(i => i.Attribute.Total),
                N = cg.Count(),
                NumberOfPeriods = 1

            })
            .OrderBy(@t => @t.Year)
            .ThenBy(@t => @t.Month);
```

If I uncommented the '.AsEnumerable()' it works perfectly as is executed on the client side, but the number of rows of the join could be too high without the GroupBy executed on the server side and sometimes I get a OutOfMemmory error or a Timeout error.

anyone know how to translate this query to a working one on Entity Framework Core 3.1.5?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: i guess this is an issue with EF Core 3.1 . Looks like there isn't any ETA for this. 
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17620

Comment: EF Core version?

Comment: @IvanStoev EF Core 3.1.5

Comment: Can't give a concrete answer w/o repro, but from what I see it could be related to the usage of navigation property after `GroupBy`. Try eliminating it by explicitly projecting everything you need, e.g. `.GroupBy(..., @t => new { @t.c.Attribute })`.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev, it solves the error but I still having some timeout errors, it seems that the translated query is not as optimized than before.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @IvanStoev for the tip on his comment, the error has gone by explicitly projecting the field needed on the GroupBy:

```
var q = _QueryService.GetSomeInformation(db, cp.Attributes, min, max);

    var query = q
        .Join(db.SomeTable
                .Where(mc => mc.Attribute.Total >= minimumValue),
            s => s.Code,
            c => c.Code,
            (s, c) => new {s, c})
        .GroupBy(@t => new {@t.c.Year, @t.c.Month}, @t => @t.c.Attribute)
        .Select(cg => new
        {

            cg.Key.Year,
            cg.Key.Month,
            P1 = cg.Average(i => i.P1),
            P2 = cg.Average(i => i.P2),
            P3 = cg.Average(i => i.P3),
            P4 = cg.Average(i => i.P4),
            P5 = cg.Average(i => i.P5),
            P6 = cg.Average(i => i.P6),
            Total = cg.Average(i => i.Total),
            N = cg.Count(),
            NumberOfPeriods = 1

        })
        .OrderBy(@t => @t.Year)
        .ThenBy(@t => @t.Month);
```